# Excel - testing two conditions in a row throughout spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple columns with things I need to summarize, but here is a simplified version:

Sheet (#1)

```
Test Group    Scenario    Test Result      
one           a           pass
one           b           fail
one           c           fail
two           a           pass
two           b           fail
two           c           pass
three         a           pass
```

And I have another Sheet (#2)

```
Test Group    Passes    Fails  Total
one           #         #      #
two           #         #      #     
three         #         #      #
```

I'm expecting results that look like:

```
Test Group    Passes    Fails  Total
one           1         2      3
two           2         1      3
three         1         0      1
```

I have been trying to create a formula which counts passes and fails in Sheet 1 based on the name of the Test Group in Sheet 2.

I'm not sure whether to use Count and If or CountIf or Countifs

I've resorted to something like =COUNTIF('Sheet 1'!C2:C4,"pass") but this does not account for the possibility that more tests can be added later, and then I'd have to update each row in the summary to use new numbers.

Is there some simple way to do this?
I'm hoping for something that looks at the pair of data (test group, test result) and summarizes it.

(I tried http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP010342339.aspx but that doesn't seem to work for me)

Comment: that would give me the whole number of passes, I would like to summarize by test group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this into a pivot table and you can do it quite easily

Insert>Pivot Table> select your range> click OK

Make the column/row/value labels look like in my picture

[image]

Comment: @EliteOctagon, if you want the spreadsheet to track any additional data added, use a named range that will return the appropriate size area. Example = the data source for the pivot table is defined as **TestResults**, and in name manager, **TestResults** is defined as `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),3)` - a simple refresh on the pivot table will include the data, instead of having to change the data source each time to add in the extra rows

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E2,$C:$C,F$1)
```

I used this in the structure below:

[image]

The total shouldn't be too difficult :)

Comment: This worked great, but it was much easier to create a pivot table

Comment: @EliteOctagon It's okay, you mentioned `COUNTIFS`, so I went from there. The only downside I can think of using the pivot table is that you'll have to refresh it each time you want updated records in the summary, but on the other hand, you'll have to add test groups each time you get a new one if you use `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Both are great solutions.